# Scrape html links Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Hello everyone I'm trying to get all href links with python by using this :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr'
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}

#Collecting links on rappel.gouv
def get_url(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def extract(soup):
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'product-content'})
    for item in results:
        item.find('a', {'class' : 'product-link'}).text.replace('','').strip()
        links = url + item.find('a', {'class' : 'product-link'})['href']

    return links

soup = get_url(url)
print(extract(soup))
```

I'm supposed to get 10 htmls links as following :

```
https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr/fiche-rappel/4571/Interne
https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr/fiche-rappel/4572/Interne
https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr/fiche-rappel/4573/Interne
https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr/fiche-rappel/4575/Interne
https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr/fiche-rappel/4569/Interne
https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr/fiche-rappel/4565/Interne
https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr/fiche-rappel/4568/Interne
https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr/fiche-rappel/4570/Interne
https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr/fiche-rappel/4567/Interne
https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr/fiche-rappel/4558/Interne
```

it actually works when I write `print` into the code as following :

```
def extract(soup):
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'product-content'})
    for item in results:
        item.find('a', {'class' : 'product-link'}).text.replace('','').strip()
        links = url + item.find('a', {'class' : 'product-link'})['href']
        print(links)

    return
```

but I'm supposed with all the links I get from this request put them into a loop so I'll get data from each of those 10 pages and store them in a database (so it means there are lines code to write after `def extract(soup)`to come.

I have tried to understand with many tutorials, I get ever one html or a `none`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to build a list of links, in your code the variable links only resets each time in the loop. Try this:

```
def extract(soup):
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'product-content'})
    links = []
    for item in results:
        item.find('a', {'class' : 'product-link'}).text.replace('','').strip()
        links.append(url + item.find('a', {'class' : 'product-link'})['href'])


    return links
```

To print each link in main code after functions:

```
soup = get_url(url)
linklist = extract(soup)
for url in linklist:
    print(url)
```

Comment: Thank you :) but I did that too, I get a result as following : `['https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr/fiche-rappel/4571/Interne', ... 'https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr/fiche-rappel/4558/Interne']` but I was wondering... let's say I name this output url_data = extract(soup), I'm going to implement `url_data` like this `request.get(url_data)` for then I use bs4, to extract data for each pages, do you think that it will work ? cause i'm afraid of this such of errors requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "['https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr']"

Comment: You can access a link in you list by an index:
`soup = get_url(url)  
linklist = extract(soup)  
print(linklist[0])  
print(linklist[1]) `

Surely you can iterate over this list in a loop.
`for url in linklist:  
    print(url)`

Comment: Thank you very much !! it very much appreciated, thanks to everyone else as well :)

Comment: One more thing: if you need to keep the starting url in a variable `url` it's better to set some different name of the variable in the last loop :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `links` variable is being rewritten inside the `for` loop.

You can create an empty list before the loop, then append the URL on each iteration.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr'
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}

#Collecting links on rappel.gouv
def get_url(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def extract(soup):
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'product-content'})
    links = []
    for item in results:
        item.find('a', {'class' : 'product-link'}).text.replace('','').strip()
        links.append(url + item.find('a', {'class' : 'product-link'})['href'])

    return links

soup = get_url(url)
print(extract(soup))
```

Comment: yes I did that too, I get a result as following : `['https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr/fiche-rappel/4571/Interne', ... 'https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr/fiche-rappel/4558/Interne']` but my question then is... let's say I name this output `url_data = extract(soup)`, I'm going to implement url_data like this `request.get(url_data)` for then I use bs4, to extract data for each pages, do you think that it will work ? cause i'm afraid of this such of errors `requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "['https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr']"`

Answer (score 0):

To use the links from the page to iterate over each products detail page collect the links in a list and return it from the funtion.

Try to name your functions more like what they are returning `get_url()` is more `get_soup()`,...

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://rappel.conso.gouv.fr'
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}

def get_soup(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def extract_product_urls(url):
    links = [url+x['href'] for x in get_soup(url).select('a.product-link')]
    return links

def extract_product_details(url):
    soup = get_soup(url)
    items = {}

    for x in soup.select('.product-desc li'):
        content = x.get_text('|', strip=True).split('|')
        items[content[0]]=content[1]

    return items

data = []

for link in extract_product_urls(url):
    data.append(extract_product_details(link))

data
```

#### Output

```
[{'Réf. Fiche\xa0:': '2021-11-0273',
  '№ de Version\xa0:': '1',
  'Origine de la fiche\xa0:': 'PLACE DU MARCHE PLACE DU MARCHE',
  'Nature juridique du rappel\xa0:': 'Volontaire',
  'Catégorie de produit': 'Alimentation',
  'Sous-catégorie de produit': 'Lait et produits laitiers',
  'Nom de la marque du produit': 'Toupargel',
  'Noms des modèles ou références': 'BATONNETS GEANTS VANILLE AMANDES',
  'Identification des produits': 'GTIN',
  'Conditionnements': '292G',
  'Date début/Fin de commercialisation': 'Du\r\n                            11/07/2019\r\n                            au\r\n                            18/09/2021',
  'Température de conservation': 'Produit à conserver au congélateur',
  'Marque de salubrité': 'EMB 35360C',
  'Zone géographique de vente': 'France entière',
  'Distributeurs': 'PLACE DU MARCHE',
  'Motif du rappel': 'Nous tenons à vous informer, que suite à une alerte européenne concernant la présence potentielle d’oxyde d’éthylène à une teneur supérieure à la limite autorisée, et comme un grand nombre d’acteurs de la distribution, nous devons procéder au rappel',
  'Risques encourus par le consommateur': 'Autres contaminants chimiques',
  'Conduite à tenir par le consommateur': 'Ne plus consommer',
  'Numéro de contact': '0805805910',
  'Modalités de compensation': 'Remboursement',
  'Date de fin de la procédure de rappel': 'samedi 26 février 2022'},
 {'Réf. Fiche\xa0:': '2021-11-0274',
  '№ de Version\xa0:': '1',
  'Origine de la fiche\xa0:': 'PLACE DU MARCHE PLACE DU MARCHE',
  'Nature juridique du rappel\xa0:': 'Volontaire',
  'Catégorie de produit': 'Alimentation',
  'Sous-catégorie de produit': 'Lait et produits laitiers',
  'Nom de la marque du produit': 'Toupargel',
  'Noms des modèles ou références': 'CREME GLACEE NOUGAT',
  'Identification des produits': 'GTIN',
  'Conditionnements': '469G',
  'Date début/Fin de commercialisation': 'Du\r\n                            28/06/2019\r\n                            au\r\n                            10/10/2021',
  'Température de conservation': 'Produit à conserver au congélateur',
  'Marque de salubrité': 'EMB 35360C',
  'Zone géographique de vente': 'France entière',
  'Distributeurs': 'PLACE DU MARCHE',
  'Motif du rappel': 'Nous tenons à vous informer, que suite à une alerte européenne concernant la présence potentielle d’oxyde d’éthylène à une teneur supérieure à la limite autorisée, et comme un grand nombre d’acteurs de la distribution, nous devons procéder au rappel',
  'Risques encourus par le consommateur': 'Autres contaminants chimiques',
  'Conduite à tenir par le consommateur': 'Ne plus consommer',
  'Numéro de contact': '0805805910',
  'Modalités de compensation': 'Remboursement',
  'Date de fin de la procédure de rappel': 'samedi 26 février 2022'},...]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, less lines, as much effective :D